# .htaccess: remove .html and redirect slash version

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On my site, all pages have .html extension and are directly off the root (i.e., site.com/page.html). I've successfully used the following .htaccess code to make .html not show:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This gives me a url like site.com/page, but in the event that a user links to or visits the url using a slash (i.e., site.com/page/), I'd like to 301 redirect to the non-slash version.

I'm having trouble integrating this part into the above code. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```